# How to locate plumbing schematics of a very old home?

Tags: plumbing

We have a break/breaks in our sewage main line, and need the plumbing schematics of house. If that is impossible then where can I find just the house blueprints?

Comment: They may not exist. Current building codes usually require filing with a local building department, but that did not exist before mid 20th century or later in many jurisdictions.

Comment: Is your house identical to other houses in the neighborhood?  Or a mirror image of other houses in the neighborhood?

Comment: Plumbing schematics are often unavailable, but a good plumber can usually figure it out.  From what is visible, they can figure out the likely way it was installed.  They can also run a camera down the line to see and locate any breaks.

Comment: As has been said; there are likely no drawings that you are thinking of. I drew the plumbing for my own house 20 years ago : basically it was just the location of sinks , tubs, etc, and the plumbers decided where to put the pipe.

Answer (score 2):

> Plumbing schematics are often unavailable, but a good plumber can usually figure it out.

...

> Current building codes usually require filing with a local building department, but that did not exist before mid 20th century or later in many jurisdictions.

Comment: A good plumber with a camera on the end of his line snake can follow and mark the location of all the sewer line piping that he can access. He can show the exact location and the depth of the line.